# How to read range values in properties file in Java

Tags: java, drools

I want to read values from Properties file as a range of values.
My Task is, calculating result based on points gained.
for example,points are,

```
<100 : some result.
101 - 110 : Some result.
111 - 120 : Some result.
121 - 130 : some result.
.....
.....
991 - 1000 : some result.
>1000 : some result.
```

Is any way of storing and getting result from Properties file instead of placing [key,value] pair from 1 to 1000, because i may get float values also?
should i have to write if else statements for all  possible conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an Array

```
String[] results = "<100,<100,<100,<100,<100,<100,<100,<100,<100,<100,result101-110,result111-120, etc".split(",");

String result = results[(value-1)/10];
```

Or you can use a NavigableMap if the ranges vary

```
NavigableMap<Double, String> map = ...
String result = map.higherEntry(value).getValue();
```

In which case the format could be `upper-limit` `result`

```
100 some result.
110 Some result.
120 Some result.
130 some result.
.....
.....
1000 Some result.
Infinity some result.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution saved my if-else coding time and makes my project as a generic.